# How to formulate a numpy submatrix view array d as a 1D matrix rather than a 2D

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This is using numpy. Here is something interestingly close to what is needed; updates to the submatrix view d can update the backing matrix a:

```
a = array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

print a

array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

d = a[1:4,1:4]

print d

array([[0, 1, 0],
[1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0]])

d[1,1]=9

print a

array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 9, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

THis is great, the 9 appears in the backing array a, as I had hoped.

OK here's the rub -- now if the requirement is instead, to formulate a numpy submatrix view array d, or some view dd of d, as a 1D matrix rather than a 2D, how do you do that? The following fails to do that.

```
dd = d.reshape(9)

print dd

array([0, 1, 0, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0])

dd[7]=7

print dd

array([0, 1, 0, 1, 9, 0, 0, 7, 0])

print a

array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 9, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

I had hoped to see the 7 appear in the backing array a.
Please note that there is no requirement to limit the d submatrix view to be 2D -- a 1D definition of the d submatrix view in the first place would be a perfectly fine formulation
if such a thing exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might find the [`flat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flat.html) method useful. As [jterrace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11923268/577088) has already pointed out, the memory that `d` uses isn't contiguous, and so `d` can't be reshaped in the usual way. However, the `flat` method doesn't return an array -- it returns a [`numpy.flatiter`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flatiter.html#numpy.flatiter) object, which is sort of like a python iterator, but allows indexed access and assignment, just like a regular array.

```
>>> d = a[1:4,1:4]
>>> dd = d.flat
>>> dd[7] = 7
>>> a
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 7, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Works great. Perfect solution.  Thank you for the able assistance! Whether the numpy.flatiter continues to operate as if it were a true 1D array within a vector math expression is my next area of research.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to create a view, you should assign to the `.shape` attribute instead of calling `.reshape`. If you read the Notes section of [numpy.reshape](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) you will see that it's not always possible to create a view of an array without copying. Watch what happens when I run your code with `.shape` instead:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
... [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
... [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
... [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
... [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
>>> d = a[1:4,1:4]
>>> d.shape
>>> d.shape = (9,)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: incompatible shape for a non-contiguous array
```

The reason this doesn't work is because the view slice you created is not contiguous. If numpy can't maintain the given data in its underlying storage mechanism efficiently, the `.reshape` function creates a copy instead.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you have is that `dd = d.reshape(9)` - is creating a *copy* of `d`, not a re-shaped *view* of `d`

Try:

```
d = a[1:4, 1:4] # updates reflected in a
d[1, 1] = 9     # updates reflected in a
d.itemset(7, 7) # 7th element regardless of dimensions
# or for multiple updates
np.put(d, [7, 3], [7, 9999]) 
print a
```